# python - How to make an "if input ==" conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to organize my games as a way of playing with python. This is my code so far:

```
Skyrim = "Skyrim"
GTAIV = "GTAIV"
GTASA = "GTASA"
Games = Skyrim + " " + GTAIV + " " + GTASA
```

That's literally it for now. Basically what I am asking is how do i make a conditional that is the equivalent of "If input == this"

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its quite simple really:

```
Skyrim = "Skyrim"
GTAIV = "Skyrim"
GTASA = "Skyrim"
Games = Skyrim + " " + GTAIV + " " + GTASA

if raw_input("Enter: ") == "Games":
    print Games
```

Output:

```
Enter: Games
Skyrim Skyrim Skyrim
```

Comment: Games.py", line 6, in <module>
    if raw_input("Enter: ") == "Games":
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Doesn't work :/

Comment: @Aiden Then you're probably using python 3, in which case, use `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: @Aiden If this worked for you, please accept the answer by pressing the tick mark to the left hand side of this answer.